# Calling from a xlsx file I get attribute error but I do not when I create the dataframe pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, ipython

I am trying to do this with two dataframes:

```
df1 = df.copy()

df1['emails'] = df1.emails.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(map(str.strip, x.split(','))) - set(blacklisted.email)))

df1 = df1[df1.emails != '']
```

when I create the dataframe with the same information myself, and it returns the same datatypes it works; for example if I create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
blacklisted=pd.DataFrame(columns=['email'],
                data=[['smith.john@hotmail.com'],['earl.bob@jpmorgan.com'],['banana.star@csu.edu'], ['london.flag@wholefoods.com'], 
                      ['soft.pretzel@utz.com']])

blacklisted.head()

 email
0   smith.john@hotmail.com
1   earl.bob@jpmorgan.com
2   banana.star@csu.edu
3   london.flag@wholefoods.com
4   soft.pretzel@utz.com
```

and another dataframe that looks like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['customerId','full name','emails'],
                data=[['208863338', 'Brit Spear', 'star.shine@cw.com'],['086423367', 'Justin Bob', 'bob.love@gem.com,ruby.blue@yahoo.com'],['902626998', 'White Ice', 'iceblue@starr.com,ice@msn.com'], ['1000826799', 'Bear Lou', 'lou.bear@visa.com'], 
                      ['1609813339',   'Ariel Do', 'ariel.d@fire.com, ariel@yahoo.com']])
print(df)



customerId      full name       emails
0   208863338   Brit Spear  star.shine@cw.com
1   086423367   Justin Bob  bob.love@gem.com,ruby.blue@yahoo.com
2   902626998   White Ice   iceblue@starr.com,ice@msn.com
3   1000826799  Bear Lou    lou.bear@visa.com
4   1609813339  Ariel Do    ariel.d@fire.com, ariel@yahoo.com
```

the above code works but when I try to call the same information from two files instead using code like this:

```
blacklisted = df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/sfiq/blacklisted.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/customers.xlsx')
```

with the exact same information as the two dataframes I created above it wont work, I get an attribute error:

```
df1['emails'] = df1.emails.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(map(str.strip, x.split(','))) - set(blacklisted.email)))
```

the error returned is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-439d1f152f33> in <module>()
----> 1 df1['emails'] = df1.emails.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(map(str.strip, x.split(','))) - set(blacklisted.email)))

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2218         else:
   2219             values = self.asobject
-> 2220             mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2221 
   2222         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:62658)()

<ipython-input-22-439d1f152f33> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df1['emails'] = df1.emails.apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(map(str.strip, x.split(','))) - set(blacklisted.email)))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Can you try `print(df.emails)` right before applying your function? One reason may be you have unexpected elements in your `df` coming from your excel. Worth to check.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have:

In `blacklisted.xlsx`:

[image]

In `customers.xlsx`:

[image]

Use `astype` before apply function like this:

```
blacklisted = pd.read_excel(r'blacklisted.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(r'customers.xlsx')
df['emails'] = df.emails.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(map(str.strip, x.split(','))) - set(blacklisted.email)))
df
```

`df` will be:

```
    customerId  full name   emails
0   208863338   Brit Spear  star.shine@cw.com
1   86423367    Justin Bob  ruby.blue@yahoo.com,bob.love@gem.com
2   902626998   White Ice   ice@msn.com,iceblue@starr.com
3   1000826799  Bear Lou    lou.bear@visa.com
4   1609813339  Ariel Do    ariel@yahoo.com,ariel.d@fire.com
```